# Peatio [error]: wrong number of arguments (2 for 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I had a problem with my withdrawal and it showed on log/peatio:amqp:withdraw_coin.output :

```
peatio:amqp:withdraw_coin: process with pid 20690 started.
I, [2019-10-07T20:36:02.789768 #20690] INFO -- : Connected to AMQP broker (prefetch: default)
I, [2019-10-07T20:38:24.291531 #20690] INFO -- : Received: Worker::WithdrawCoin {"id":14,"locale":"en"}
I, [2019-10-07T20:38:24.468275 #20690] INFO -- : [Withdraw]: coin
I, [2019-10-07T20:38:24.468464 #20690] INFO -- : Making class WOA_BTC(coin)
I, [2019-10-07T20:38:24.468735 #20690] INFO -- : WOA_BTC {"method":"getbalance","params":[],"id":"jsonrpc"}
I, [2019-10-07T20:38:24.620932 #20690] INFO -- : {"result"=>59901.1999808, "error"=>nil, "id"=>"jsonrpc"}
I, [2019-10-07T20:38:24.621430 #20690] INFO -- : Making class WOA_BTC(coin)
I, [2019-10-07T20:38:24.621795 #20690] INFO -- : [error]: wrong number of arguments (2 for 3)
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Ruby 2.2.7
Bundle 1.9.2
Rails 4.0.12

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try to make this change to your files.
In my case, it solved this problem.

app/models/worker/withdraw_coin.rb:
https://gist.github.com/DigitalCoin1/471796cb0bdc929d678ab61a8abe326a

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your link in the space provided here.

Comment: Since he did not post the source used, I am taking into account the official code.
Because it is open source and because it has different versions, each user can get parts or the entire file that I have made available.